# Filling the viewport area of a orthographic camera with an image (libgdx)

Tags: java, libgdx

So im trying to get the whole area of the viewport and then use the coordinates to draw images in the camera's viewport. So if the camera moves I can fill it with one image the length and the width of the viewport:

[image: Camera Viewport]

I just want the take the gray area in the picture (which is the camera's viewport) and fill it with this image.

[image: Sample Image]

So no matter what the camera's x and y coordinates are it will continue drawing the bottom image giving the effect of an infinite space and also the effect of moving.

EDIT:
Code I've tried so far

```
TextureRegion bg = ...;
int imageWidth = bg.getRegionWidth();
int imageHeight = bg.getRegionHeight();

batch.begin();
for (int x = 0;x<(camera.viewportWidth / imageWidth) + 2;x++) {
        for (int y = 0;y<(camera.viewportHeight / imageHeight) + 2;y++) {
                batch.draw(bg, ((camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth / 2) + ((x - 1) * imageWidth)), ((camera.position.y - camera.viewportHeight / 2) + ((y - 1) * imageHeight)));
        }
}
batch.end();
```

EDIT 2:
Thinking about getting the viewport area of the camera and adding tiles to a list that are viewable in the viewport area. Then as the camera moves remove the ones out of the list that are out of view and when a new area comes into view add new tiles. Then render all the tiles in the list.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @PhilAnderson Ive tried this http://pastebin.com/0E7hYiPv and it fills the image in the viewport but it's static and doesnt look like your moving through space. Not sure how to get it to look like youre moving.

Comment: I'm afraid pastebin is blocked here. It would be better if you edited your question to include some code that shows the problem.

Comment: @PhilAnderson Edited my post with the code ive already tried